# Как найти все матрицы состоящие из заданного числа элементов, с ненулевым определителем?

Tags: математика, комбинаторика, матрицы

Имеется матрица 7×7. Элементами матрицы может быть любой из 33 элементов. Если мы перебором всевозможные матрицы, то количество комбинаций будет равно  33^49. Это очень долго для компьютера. Но мне не нужны все матрицы, мне нужны лишь те, которые имеет ненулевой определитель. Какие свойства матриц можно использовать, чтобы ускорить поиск неворожденных матриц? Ведь количество таких матриц ограничено в сравнении с общим количеством комбинаций. Какие будет предложения?

Comment: Как насчет того, чтобы сократить количество комбинаций до 32^7? Если комбинировать собственные значения без нуля? И уже на собственном векторе матрицы, вроде называемый следом , строить сами матрицы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В постановке ОП задача нерешаема.

Если 33 ненулевых элемента не равны попарно, то существует 33^7 = 42618442977 вариантов их размещения на главной диагонали, .
Если это не смущает, можно разместить те же элементы в любой из 7! = 5040 "ладейных" расстановок (по одному на строку и по одному на столбец).
И такие коэффициенты можно добавлять многократно (например, использовать свойства блочных матриц).

UPD.

1. Если задать элементы ниже главной диагонали нулевыми, элементы главной диагонали - ненулевыми, а элементы выше главной диагонали - произвольными, то определитель будет ненулевым (и равным произведению элементов главной диагонали).
2. Если нуль использовать нельзя, то можно заполнить матрицу ниже главной диагонали одним и тем же элементом, главную диагональ - неравными ему элементами, а матрицу выше главной диагонали - произвольно. В этом случае определитель будет произведением разностей элементов главной диагонали и "нижнего" элемента.
3. Перестановка строк и столбцов матрицы может изменить только знак её определителя.
4. Таким образом, количество ненулевых определителей не меньше, чем
   33 * 32<sup>7</sup> * 33<sup>21</sup> * 7! = 5040 * 33<sup>22</sup> * 32<sup>7</sup> ≈ 4 * 10<sup>47</sup>